# How long does the new dwellers queue last?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When clicking the radio room icon that attracts a new dweller to your vault, how long will they stay queued out in front of the vault for before giving up?  Or will they?

I'm at max population and would rather not kill existing dwellers to accommodate them in my vault.

Comment: If you can kill just one dweller you can clear your queue by taking them into the vault and immediately sending them out to explore with no gear. Once they die, you can do the next one until the queue is finally clear!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They do not give up, and will queue for an indefinite period of time.

They will disappear momentarily during raider/deathclaw attacks, but move back into position afterwards.

Comment: Does this apply to dwellers that I have sent into the wasteland (and have returned) as well?